# Mysql query output right, count wrong

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    count(A.gross_c) AS cnt, 
    SUM(A.gross_c) AS Gross_c, 
    B.store_name
FROM hr_location_c_verified A 
JOIN hr_stores B ON A.c_location = B.id
WHERE A.c_ref_fkid IS NULL
GROUP BY A.c_location
```

I am executing this query, the output result coming correct, but count showing wrong.

Please help me.

Comment: What are you trying to count?

Comment: Please show some sample data and what's wrong count is comming?

Comment: I am trying to count the number of rows, Gross_c and store_name coming correct but cnt output wrong

Comment: group by expression should always contain non aggregated colums of the select (here store_name, and add c_location on the select), else strange things may happen. other databases would reject your query as invalid.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely because of your **JOIN**, producing more rows.

One way is to use the **DISTINCT** keyword.

```
SELECT 
    count(DISTINCT A.gross_c) AS cnt, 
    SUM(A.gross_c) AS Gross_c, 
    B.store_name FROM hr_location_c_verified A 
JOIN hr_stores B ON A.c_location = B.id
WHERE A.c_ref_fkid IS NULL
GROUP BY A.c_location
```